# Calculating p-value using non-parametric bootstrap

Tags: r

Let's say I'm given a sample, X. My professor says that to find the p-value using non-paramaetric bootstrap. I should adjust the sample mean by doing:

adjustedX = X - mean(X) + mu_not

Then he says to bootstrap the adjustedX, and return the mean.
After getting a list sample means, the p-value can be calculated as the proportion of bootstrap sample means that are less than the observed sample mean.

I've simulated this in R, but I'm not getting anything close to the true p-value.

Here's my R function:

```
pvalue = function(Samples, mu_not) {
  X.boot = X - mean(X) + mu_not
  bootstrap = sapply(1:Samples, function(a){
    single = sample(X.boot, length(X.boot), replace=TRUE)
    return(mean(single))
  })
  return(mean(mu_not < bootstrap))
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: why not use `boot` package?

Comment: Professor wants us to calculate the p-value using several different methods, including the boot package.

Comment: p-value of what? what is the true p value?

Comment: The true p-value is about 5%, I'm getting around 50% with the function above.

Comment: No. I am asking what your hypothesis is. Didn't your prof mention any thing about quantile?

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. The null Hypothesis is Ho: u >= u.not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the null hypothesis you mentioned in the comments `Ho: u >= u.not`  this should work:

```
 pvalue = function(Samples, mu_not) {
     X.boot = X
     bootstrap = sapply(1:Samples, function(a){
         single = sample(X.boot, length(X.boot), replace=TRUE)
         return(mean(single))
     })
     return(mean(mu_not < bootstrap))
 }
```

Comment: Why did we get rid of adjusting the sample mean?

Comment: It is not necessary for the null hypothesis you mentioned. If you wish to adjust for the sake of adhering to your professor's guidelines, you could change it to `X.boot = X - mu_not` and `return(mean(0 < bootstrap))`.

Comment: Ahh, Thanks to your answer, I figured it out. We can leave the adjusted sample mean, and return the proportion of bootstrap that are less than the sample mean that we began with. Thanks.